# req.body.stripeToken is undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to use $http to post a form to my nodejs server. When I do the post, I will go to my server and try to get the variable stripeToken using req.body.stripeToken, but this returns undefined.

When I try the post request using the method="post" and action="http://localhost:3000/api/posts" attributes on the form in my html file, it works like a charm. This is my reason to believe that my server side code is OK, but that there is something wrong with my $http request.

I've read several posts about this problem, but I have yet to see a working solution for me.

solutions from other posts:

- define configurations before you define your routes in the server file.
- add the body-parser middleware in the server file.
- define headers for your http request.

I have tried these solutions, but none worked. Ofcourse I can use the method that works, but since I'm using AngularJS I would like to do it using $http.

$http post request:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts',
            data: form.get(0),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).
            then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
```

What I'm trying to send (form.get(0)):

```
<form id="payment-form" ng-controller="paymentController" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Card Number</span>
            <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
            <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
        </label>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>CVC</span>
            <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
        </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" ng-click="generateToken()" disabled="">Buy Now</button>
<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="tok_18G8jbEFG6WB0FQNYyIbXJWF"></form>
```

Server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var stripe = require("stripe")("secret code");


var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

app.listen(3000);

app.post("/api/posts", function (req, res) {
    console.log('in post--server');
    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
    console.log(stripeToken);
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 1000, // amount in cents
        currency: "eur",
        source: stripeToken,
        description: "Example charge"
    }, function (err, charge) {
        if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
            res.send("the card has been declined");
        } else res.send("transaction completed");
    });
});
```

console.log(req.body); gives the following answer:

```
{ '{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{"jQuery221039077944120836341":{"events":{"click":': {   '{"type":"click","origType":"click","guid":3,"namespace":""}': { '{"type":"$destroy","origType":"$destroy","guid":1,"namespace":""},{"type":"$destroy","origType":"$destroy","guid":2,"namespace":""}': '' } } }
```

I really tried looking for an answer, but found none. So please forgive me if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: try `console.log(req.body)` to see what else it has

Comment: what do you get if you log `form.get(0)`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I've added the response in my question, but I can't see what's going wrong. I mean, it is obvious that there is somehting wrong with the log, but I can't tell what's causing it.

Comment: @andyk the code snippet I added about what I send, is the log I get from form.get(0).

Comment: @MathiasSamyn what is `form.get(0)`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly the second code snippet in my question is form.get(0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below implementation should work, `form.get(0)` returns jQuery event, not form values

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts',
    data: $('#payment-form').serialize(),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: yes! this answer works, thanks a lot. I used form.get(0) because the other method I mentioned did: form.get(0).submit, so I thought that form.get(0) was the variable that was send with the post request, guess I was wrong...